# Substring function in PHP

Tags: php, strings

I wrote this function to test if one string is a substring of another.

I'm curious to get some feedback on the implementation - does my solution seem reasonable? Is the code "well written"? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
<?php
function isSubStr($a, $b){
    if(!strpos($a, $b[0])){
        return false;
    }
    $result = true;
    $start = strpos($a, $b[0]);
    for ($pos = 0; $pos < strlen($b); $pos++){
            if($b[$pos] != $a[$start + $pos]){
                $result = false;
            }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Tests below:

```
<?php
require 'solution.php';
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class myTests extends TestCase {
  public function testExamples() {
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cat', 'at'), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cat', 'fluffy'), false);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cheeze', 'ee'), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('snow', 'o'), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('octopus', 'top'), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('octopus', 'zzz'), false);
  }
}
```

Comment: You do know that `strpos()` can find the entire string? And that you have other functions which does similar things like `stristr()` and `strchr()`?

Comment: Try testing `isSubStr('ababc', 'abc')`.  It will return `false` but obviously is true.  Also `isSubStr('abc', 'abc')`.

Comment: Lots of useful tips. It didn't occur to me that is was so simple (not seeing the wood for the trees..)
`function isSubStr($a, $b){
 if(strpos($a, $b) === false){ // position 0 different from false
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the obvious fact that you're reinventing the wheel as this functionality is already present in php, here are some comments to your code:

- *Strange to use `strpos()`* – If you want to reinvent the wheel, then I wouldn't use `strpos()` at all.
- *Doesn't restart checks* – As commented upon by mdfst13, cases like `ababc vs abc` fails, as you don't restart the test if the first candidate fails.
- *Too long substrings gives index errors* – Testing with `octopus vs pussy` results in index errors on the source string.
- *`$a` and `$b` are not really good names* – They don't convey anything regarding their intended purpose, as `$source` and `$substr` would do.*
- *No comments* – It always nice to have a little comments to indicate what you are trying to achieve in a code block.

So an even more basic version which implements these comments could look like:

```
function isSubStr($source, $substr) {
  $len_src = strlen($source);
  $len_sub = strlen($substr);
  $max_start_pos = $len_src - $len_sub;

  // If longer, there isn't room for it
  if ($max_start_pos < 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // Find start position for substring
  $pos = 0;
  while ($pos <= $max_start_pos) {

    // Check if we have a valid start position
    if ($source[$pos] == $substr[0]) {

       // Assume it is a good candidate, and verify this
       $foundCandidate = true;

      // Check for equality between source and substring,
      // and verify length of both strings
      for ($subIdx = 0, $orgIdx = $pos; 
           $orgIdx < $len_src && $subIdx < $len_sub;
           $orgIdx++, $subIdx++) {

        if ($source[$orgIdx] != $substr[$subIdx]) {
          $foundCandidate = false;
          break;
        } 
      }

      // If we exited previous loop due to exhausting the substring,
      // and not have a falsified candidate we have a match 
      if ($foundCandidate && $len_sub == $subIdx) {
            return true;
      }
    }

    $pos++;
  }

  // Passed max start position without finding start of substr
  if ($pos > $max_start_pos) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This code passes for all of the following cases:

```
public function testExamples() {
      $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cat', 'at'), true);
      $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cat', 'fluffy'), false);
      $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cheeze', 'ee'), true);
      $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('snow', 'o'), true);
      $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('octopus', 'top'), true);
      $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('octopus', 'zzz'), false);
      $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('octopus', 'pussy'), false);
      $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('octopus', 'tops'), false);
      $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('ababc', 'abc'), true);
      $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('abc', 'abc'), true); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @holroy gave a good answer, regarding the function itself.  I wanted to add some thoughts around your unit tests.

With `assertEquals`, you are supposed to put the **expected** value as the first argument, not the second.

```
$this->assertEquals(true, isSubStr('cat', 'at'));
```

But in your case you **really** should just use `assertTrue()` or `assertFalse()` since you are testing for boolean values.

```
  public function testExamples() {
        $this->assertTrue(isSubStr('cat', 'at'));
        $this->assertFalse(isSubStr('cat', 'fluffy'));
        $this->assertTrue(isSubStr('cheeze', 'ee'));
        $this->assertTrue(isSubStr('snow', 'o'));
        $this->assertTrue(isSubStr('octopus', 'top'));
        $this->assertFalse(isSubStr('octopus', 'zzz'));
  }
```

Now you may say that "Hey, I don't like having `assertTrue` cases mixed in there with `assertFalse`."  To which, I would say "Exactly! Why not group your assertions together make them more readable."

```
  public function testExamples() {
        $this->assertTrue(isSubStr('cat', 'at'));
        $this->assertTrue(isSubStr('cheeze', 'ee'));
        $this->assertTrue(isSubStr('snow', 'o'));
        $this->assertTrue(isSubStr('octopus', 'top'));
        $this->assertFalse(isSubStr('cat', 'fluffy'));
        $this->assertFalse(isSubStr('octopus', 'zzz'));
  }
```

Now your test code would probably be considered easier to read because you have naturally grouped the true and false cases together.

And then you might say "Well that is cool.  Now that I have them grouped together like that, I realize I have line after line of code that look exactly the same, but only have differing values."  To which, I would reply, "Yes, you do.  Perhaps there is a better way?"

Enter data providers:

```
public function trueDataProvider() {
    return [
        ['cat', 'at'],
        ['cheeze', 'ee'],
        ['snow', 'o'],
        ['octopus', 'top']
    ];

public function falseDataProvider() {
    return [
        ['cat', 'fluffy'],
        ['octopus', 'zzz']
    ];
}

/**
 * @dataProvider trueDataProvider
 */
public testIsSubStringReturnsTrue($haystack, $needle) {
    $this->assertTrue(isSubStr($haystack, $needle));
}

/**
 * @dataProvider falseDataProvider
 */
public testIsSubStringReturnsFalse($haystack, $needle) {
    $this->assertFalse(isSubStr($haystack, $needle));
}
```

Now, you might say, "This is super cool.  I can easily test a bunch of different data sets without having to write a bunch of assertions."  To which I might add. "Yes.  And here is where the real power of unit tests come in, as it is really easy to start throwing **edge cases** into the mix. Let's revisit our `falseDataProvider` to see how."

```
public function falseDataProvider() {
    return [
        ['cat', 'fluffy'],
        ['octopus', 'zzz'],
        ['', ''], // edge case
        ['', 'abc'], // edge case
        [null, null], // edge case
        ['string', null], // edge case
        ['null', 'string'], // edge case
        [[], 'string'], // edge case
        // and so on.  Try to break your code.
        // what should happen when some of these unexpected values are passed?
    ];
}
```

By easily being able to throw edge cases against your unit under test, you can more easily explore what happens when unexpected (not "happy path") values are passed and decide how you might want to modify that unit to give it more resilient behavior (for example, throwing exceptions if unexpected parameter types/values are passed).

So perhaps you have modified your method to validate the parameters as strings:

```
function isSubStr($haystack, $needle) {
    if (!is_string($haystack) || !is_string($needle)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Feed me strings!');
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you could add another test case to  make sure this is happening

```
public function invalidDataProvider() {
    return [
        [null, null],
        ['string', null],
        [null, 'string'],
        [0, 0],
        [[], 'string'],
        // etc.
    ];
}

/**
 * @dataProvider invalidDataProvider
 * @expectException InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function testIsSubStrThrowsException($haystack, $needle) {
    isSubStr($haystack, $needle);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful :)